# how to query all where number from greatest then add limit after the query

Tags: mysql

Hi Everyone Hope you can help me with this. this is the sample table

```
ID     name      num
1      A         34
2      B         54
3      C         24
4      D         3
5      E         100
```

First, I want to select all from the greatest `num`. Then after selecting all add another query to limit the first query to 3. So the ouput should be.

```
ID     name      num
5      E         100
2      B         54
1      A         24
```

The problem is I don't how do something like query all from greatest to lowest then after that query add a limit. Since the greatest is on row "5" if I say `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY num DESC LIMIT 0,3` the query would just stop to the 3rd row and won't get the largest because the largest num is on row 5. Help!

Comment: plz share your table screen or format your question

Comment: Did you actually try that sql command? I am pretty sure it will give you the three rows with the largest num value. (You have a typo in your output, Row 1 has a num value of 34 as per your sample)

Comment: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7e4278/1/0)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY `table`.`num` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 3
```

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
 select * from test order by num desc limit 3
```

### [fiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d2690/1)

Answer (score 0):

Try to make your num column data type to a number data type such as int, bigint, double etc. You definitely cannot sort it by num if you are using varchar/String data type for your num column.